# Commit everything to a SVN Repo

Tags: svn

I have a folder which is a checkout of a SVN repository. The files in this folder are changed very often, new files get created and old files are deleted.

How can I easily commit all changes in the repository to the remove svn server? Typically I first would have to issue `svn delete [all deleted files and directories recursivly]`, then `svn add [all added files and directories recursivly]` and then `svn ci` for commit. Can this somehow be automated?

I thought about creating a bash-script which parses `svn status`, but there must be a better solution?!

One thing is important: the svn-ignore properties must NOT be ignored.

Comment: I don't know if there's a better way (I can't think of one), but this doesn't sound like a particularly long or difficult script to write.

Comment: We had a similar situation with [Adobe Robohelp](http://www.adobe.com/products/robohelp.html) files. I was able to do the delete everything/add everything business, but it made a big mess of our svn log. What we did was zip up the Robohelp files and just commit the zip file. That made the change in our repository to a single file which made our history more bearable. Completely adding and deleting a whole directory makes it impossible to do diffs, etc. So, I didn't believe we lost anything zipping everything up in a single file and only committing that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At least for the deletion task parsing `svn status` is the solution, but it can be done very quickly:

```
svn delete $( svn status | sed -e '/^!/!d' -e 's/^!//' )
```

The adding can also be done the same way:

```
svn add $( svn status | sed -e '/^?/!d' -e 's/^?//' )
```

-or- even more simple:

```
svn add . --force
```

btw: Both stated `svn add` commands consider your `svn:ignore` properties and don’t add ignored files.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to `DerVO` for the answer, I wrote the following script which first deletes all files and then adds all new one. For savety purposes the delete-command asks for every file (because `svn delete` physically deletes the file)

```
#!/bin/bash

HERE=$(cd $(dirname ${BASH_SOURCE[0]}) > /dev/null && pwd)
PROG="${0##*/}"

cd $HERE
svn status | grep ^\! | sed 's/^\!\s*//' | tr '\n' '\0' | xargs -0 -n 1 -pr svn remove
svn status | grep ^\? | sed 's/^\?\s*//' | tr '\n' '\0' | xargs -0 -n 1 -pr svn add
svn commit -m "Work of `date`"
svn up
```

Comment: It would be better to have the svn up as the first step, and stop the script if there's an error status (e.g. conflict).